# Salesforce HTML help

Tags: email, html

How can I get the HTML email template to look like the Outlook email?  it should be Calibri 11 pt. text.  Also, the customer's First Name should pull into the template, just after the "Hi".  Thanks!  Pat

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]